# How to properly pass Iterators to a function in Rust

Tags: rust, iterator

I want to pass Iterators to a function, which then computes some value from these iterators.
I am not sure how a robust signature to such a function would look like.
Lets say I want to iterate f64.
You can find the code in the playground: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=c614429c541f337adb102c14518cf39e

My first attempt was

```
fn dot(a : impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = f64>,b : impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = f64>) -> f64 {
    a.zip(b).map(|(x,y)| x*y).sum()
}
```

This fails to compile if we try to iterate over slices

So you can do

```
fn dot<'a>(a : impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'a f64>,b : impl std::iter::Iterator<Item = &'a f64>) -> f64 {
    a.zip(b).map(|(x,y)| x*y).sum()
}
```

This fails to compile if I try to iterate over mapped Ranges.
(Why does the compiler requires the livetime parameters here?)

So I tried to accept references and not references generically:

```
pub fn dot<T : Borrow<f64>, U : Borrow<f64>>(a : impl std::iter::Iterator::<Item = T>, b: impl std::iter::Iterator::<Item = U>) -> f64 {
    a.zip(b).map(|(x,y)| x.borrow()*y.borrow()).sum()
}
```

This works with all combinations I tried, but it is quite verbose and I don't really understand every aspect of it.

Are there more cases?

What would be the best practice of solving this problem?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

There is no *right* way to write a function that can accept `Iterator`s, but there are some general principles that we can apply to make your function general and easy to use.

1. Write functions that accept `impl IntoIterator<...>`. Because all `Iterator`s implement `IntoIterator`, this is strictly more general than a function that accepts only `impl Iterator<...>`.
2. `Borrow<T>` is the right way to abstract over `T` and `&T`.
3. When trait bounds get verbose, it's often easier to read if you write them in `where` clauses instead of in-line.

With those in mind, here's how I would probably write `dot`:

```
fn dot<I, J>(a: I, b: J) -> f64
where
    I: IntoIterator,
    J: IntoIterator,
    I::Item: Borrow<f64>,
    J::Item: Borrow<f64>,
{
    a.into_iter()
        .zip(b)
        .map(|(x, y)| x.borrow() * y.borrow())
        .sum()
}
```

However, I also agree with [TobiP64's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57544342/3650362) in that this level of generality may not be necessary in every case. This `dot` is nice because it can accept a wide range of arguments, so you can call `dot(&some_vec, some_iterator)` and it just works. It's optimized for readability at the *call site*. On the other hand, if you find the `Borrow` trait complicates the definition too much, there's nothing wrong with optimizing for readability at the *definition*, and forcing the caller to add a `.iter().copied()` sometimes. The only thing I would definitely change about the first `dot` function is to replace `Iterator` with `IntoIterator`.

Answer (score 2):

You can iterate over slices with the first `dot` implementation like that:

```rust
dot([0, 1, 2].iter().cloned(), [0, 1, 2].iter().cloned());
```

(https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.cloned)
or

```rust
dot([0, 1, 2].iter().copied(), [0, 1, 2].iter().copied());
```

(https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.copied)

> Why does the compiler requires the livetime parameters here?

As far as I know every reference in rust has a lifetime, but the compiler can infer simple it in cases. In this case, however the compiler is not yet smart enough, so you need to tell it how long the references yielded by the iterator lives.

> Are there more cases?

You can always use iterator methods, like the solution above, to get an iterator over `f64`, so you don't have to deal with lifetimes or generics.

> What would be the best practice of solving this problem?

I would recommend the first version (and thus leaving it to the caller to transform the iterator to `Iterator<f64>`), simply because it's the most readable.

Comment: Does the clone method do actual copies of the slice? Or can this be elided?

Comment: It doesn't copy the slice as a whole, but every element when it's needed. That's equivalent to dereferencing a `&f64`. You could also write `iter.map(|v| *v)`.

Comment: What about more complex types, which are not so cheap to copy?

Comment: In this case you would want to iterate over references (like version 2 of `dot`)