# Iterator types in Rust

Tags: rust

I'm learning rust and ran into the problem.  I have this MCVE:

```
fn main() {
    let mut line = String::new();
    std::io::stdin()
        .read_line(&mut line)
        .expect("Failed to read line");

    handle_tokens( line.split_ascii_whitespace() );
}

fn handle_tokens( mut it: std::str::SplitAsciiWhitespace ) {
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}",s),
        }
    }
}
```

[`String::split_ascii_whitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/primitive.str.html#method.split_ascii_whitespace) returns a [`SplitAsciiWhitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitAsciiWhitespace.html) object so I've used that in the signature of `handle_tokens`, but `std::str::SplitAsciiWhitespace` is an extremely specific type. A generic iterator to a list of strings makes more sense, so that I can choose `split_whitespace` or maybe just a generic list of strings.

**How can I use documentation or compiler errors to generalize the signature of `handle_tokens`?**

---

Here's my failed attempt to answer the question on my own:

I can see that [`SplitAsciiWhitespace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/str/struct.SplitAsciiWhitespace.html) "Trait Implementations" include:

```
impl<'a> Iterator for SplitWhitespace<'a>
```

This is where `next()` comes from (I had to inspect source code to verify that).  Therefore, I tried using an iterator with `fn handle_tokens( mut it: Iterator ) {` but:

```
error[E0191]: the value of the associated type `Item` (from trait `std::iter::Iterator`) must be specified
  --> src/main.rs:10:27
   |
10 | fn handle_tokens( mut it: Iterator ) {
   |                           ^^^^^^^^ help: specify the associated type: `Iterator<Item = Type>`
```

Ok, so `Iterator` is too generic to use...  I need to tell the compiler what it's wrapping.  That makes sense, otherwise I wouldn't be able to dereference it.  I had to look in the [source code](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/str/mod.rs.html#4610-4627) again to see how `SplitWhitespace` implements an Iterator and saw  `type Item = &'a str;` so I tried to specify the `Item` with `fn handle_tokens( mut it: Iterator<Item = &str>)`, but:

```
error[E0277]: the size for values of type `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = &str> + 'static)` cannot be known at compilation time
  --> src/main.rs:10:19
   |
10 | fn handle_tokens( mut it: Iterator<Item = &str> ) {
   |                   ^^^^^^ doesn't have a size known at compile-time
   |
   = help: the trait `std::marker::Sized` is not implemented for `(dyn std::iter::Iterator<Item = &str> + 'static)`
   = note: to learn more, visit <https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch19-04-advanced-types.html#dynamically-sized-types-and-the-sized-trait>
   = note: all local variables must have a statically known size
   = help: unsized locals are gated as an unstable feature
```

Ok, so I need to specify a size as well.  That's strange because while I know the size of `str` can't be known at compile-time, the size of `&str` should be.

At this point I'm very stuck.  I'm also surprised that source-code inspection is necessary when Rust seems to provide such a great built-in documentation support.  That makes me think that the method I'm using to answer this question is wrong.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly pass Iterators to a function in Rust](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57543399/how-to-properly-pass-iterators-to-a-function-in-rust)

Comment: At my (beginner) level, it's hard to comprehend that answer.  I'm sure it's not wrong, but adding the `where` `IntoIterator` and `Borrow` isn't something I've gotten to yet.  @Kitsu's answer is very clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You at the right path actually. `next` is indeed defined at the `Iterator` and that is the one you need to use. The thing you missed is that `Iterator` is a *trait` actually, not a type. Type can be bounded by a trait, so here generics come handy:

```rust
fn handle_tokens<'a, I: Iterator<Item = &'a str>>(mut it: I) { .. }
```

There's also a special impl-trait syntax which can be used instead:

```rust
fn handle_tokens<'a>(mut it: impl Iterator<Item = &'a str>) { .. }
```

However, the last example cannot be called with an explicitly specified type, i.e. `handle_tokens::<SplitAsciiWhitespace>(iter)`

Comment: In practice, you would generally use `IntoIterator` instead of `Iterator` if you want the funciton to be as generic as possible.

Answer (score 3):

`fn handle_tokens` uses `fn next` from `Iterator` trait and require `Display` trait on the items of the Iterator, so you can make this function generic.

```rust
use std::fmt::Display;
fn handle_tokens<T>(mut tokens: T)
where
    T: Iterator,
    <T as Iterator>::Item: Display,
{
    loop {
        match tokens.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}", s),
        }
    }
}
```

Or you can `.collect()` iterator

```rust
let tokens = line.split_ascii_whitespace().collect::<Vec<_>>()
```

I see you tried using `dyn`. It's called [trait objects](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch17-02-trait-objects.html).

```rust
fn handle_tokens3(it: &mut dyn Iterator<Item = &str>) {
    loop {
        match it.next() {
            None => return,
            Some(s) => println!("{}", s),
        }
    }
}
```

[Link to the playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=012e007b93009635dfed48f219a234cd)

Comment: I tried `dyn` because a warning suggested that.  I'm just doing the exercizes in chapter 8 of the same book (you linked to chap 17).  Good to know this will all make sense soon.

Comment: Beware that using `dyn` has consequences / runtime cost, it means you're dealing with an object through a virtual function table (vtable) and method calls on such an object will be indirect. Use it only if you know that that's what you need.